# Updating Formik initialValues via array push does not refresh initial values/form via csv file upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, papaparse

I have the following Formik initial values setup:

```
const INITIAL_VALUES = {
  taskName: 'Test',
  taskNotes: 'Some notes',
  areaGroups: [
     {
       name: Area Group 1,
       areaInfo: [
          {
             areaName: "Area 1",
             areaCode: null
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
};
```

What I am then doing is providing the user the option of loading a CSV file in order to avoid the user from entering further `areaInfo` data via the frontend form.

The following code seems to add the loaded CSV values to the `areaInfo` array, which I can see from a `console.log(values)` but doesn't actually update/refresh the INITIAL_VALUES above or form.

The thing is though, when I click into the `areaName` form field within the `areaInfo` array, it then refreshes and displays my loaded CVS data but doesn't display it after I select the csv file to load/parse?

My component code for this is as follows and is using `react-dropzone` and `papaparse` npm packages:

```
const PerformUpload = ({ values }) => {

    const formikProps = useFormikContext()  
    const classes = useStyles();

    const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {      
        acceptedFiles
            .filter((file) => file.type === "text/csv")
            .forEach(async (file) => {
                const text = await file.text();
                const result = parse(text, { header: true });
                const myData = result.data

                myData.map((data) => (
                  values.areaGroups[0].areaInfo.push(
                      {
                        "areaName": data.areaname,
                        "areaCode": data.areacode
                      }
                  )
                ))
            });            
      }, []);  
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });  

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
         <section className="container">
          <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropZone'})}>      
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <p>Drag files here or click to select a file</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        </React.Fragment>
      )      
  }
```

I am performing the push to the `values.areaGroups[0].areaInfo` array but not sure if this correct as it doesn't refresh the frontend/initial values until I physically click on the field.

FYI, this `PerformUpload` component is being called from within:

```
<Formik
   enableReinitialize={true}       
   initialValues={INITIAL_VALUES}
   ....
```

Not sure what I am missing/doing wrong?

Comment: because your initial values always empty. To solve this use this form _initialValues taskName: yourstate ? yourstate  : ' '_

Comment: @Rahul - I actually forgot to add some values to my initial state that should've been there to begin with. With your response, I am not entirely sure what you mean. Could you possibly provide further details/example code, in relation to my code above, that might assist me with solving my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by using Formik's `setFieldValue` prior to pushing the data into my initial values.